# Pass form parameter to child object in jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation, with this code:

```
$("#demo").validate({
  rules : {
    password : { required : true, }, 
    password2 : { required : true, }, 
  },
  messages: {
    password : { required: "This field is required.",},
    password2 : { required: "This field is required.",},
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      resizable: false,
      height:250,
      width:500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        OK : function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
      }
    });
  }, 
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass the `form` from `submitHandler` function going to the button object function. Once they click on OK, it submit's the form.

Comment: Passing this internal parameter is a non-issue; `form` merely represents `$("#demo")`, so use `$("#demo")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for jQuery to send form after "OK" is clicked, you need to construct your form as follows:

```
<form id="demo" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <input type="text" name="password2" />

  <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Success"> Thank you, success message</div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This allows the "OK" Button to be recognized by jQuery validation. Note that the dialog should be inside the form before the submit button.

Comment: Impossible for anyone else to solve this without seeing your HTML markup.

Comment: While that is true, I wouldn't have known that the problem was all about my html markup.

Comment: Regardless, you don't have to know the problem is in the markup since it should have been included all along.  Without your markup, we cannot replicate anything.  Point being, as per this site's FAQ, include enough code to construct a concise demo.  Also see:  http://sscce.org

Comment: I get what you mean, and I have read the article. Thanks for the feedback about SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

In the jQuery Validate plugin, the `form` parameter merely represents your `form` object.  In this case `form` represents the same exact thing as `$("#demo")`.  Since you're trying to use it within the `.dialog()` method, `form` may not be recognized.

Just see if this works any better...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:250,
        width:500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK : function() {
                $("#demo").submit();
            }
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: I see what the problem was now. The form does not recognize the "OK" button because the `<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>` was not inside the form. This means that the `<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>` should be inside the form named `#demo` in order for "OK" button to work and submit the form.

Comment: @FranzNoel, another reason why it's so important to include all the relevant code including the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `form` parameter from the 'OK' button handler.  You are shadowing the `form` parameter from the `submitHandler`.

Comment: But, the problem requires the use of "Ok" to submit.

Comment: That's fine, I'm not saying to remove the "Ok" button or its handler.  I'm just saying you need to remove the `form` argument that is being passed to the "Ok" button handler because it is hiding the `form` argument that is passed to the `submitHandler` function.  The `form` argument in the "Ok" button handler will probably be null or undefined anyway since I don't believe the button handlers are passed anything as arguments by the jQuery UI dialog plugin.  http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: Just a helpful information: The `form` parameter seems to have been able to pass the value to the `submitHandler` successfully (but only if the dialog is inside the `form`).